# How to take care of CSRF & XSS attacks in Single page applications without using cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xss, csrf

We are having a mobile website which is a single page application style(cfmanifest to load cache), but after login after 5 to 10 page navigation user has to submit some confidential data to BE in a form but this form is dynamically generated in Front end before submission, how to take care of **CSRF**(*Cross-Site Request Forgery*) & **XSS**(*Cross-Site Scripting*) attacks in such cases? ( cookies usage is not allowed ).

Our application uses **Jquery+RequireJs+BackboneJs+Handlebar** templates .

Answer (score 0):

If cookies is not allowed try using sessions... before the form is loaded.. some random string or hash token must be stored in server. then the token must be passed to the form as hidden.. when submitting.. the server check if the hidden token matches the session token.